# Вконтакте сообщения VK Me

Tags: вконтакте

В приложении ВКонтакте: при переходе на сообщения, открывается приложение VK Me (приложение мессенджер от ВК). Это очень бесит. Как можно отключить VK Me, чтоб сообщения открывались в самом приложении Вконтакте? 
(VK Me - где то читал что это приложение тестируется в Казахстане, но у моих знакомых такого нет, у них обычный мессенджер ВК)

Comment: При переходе на сообщения требуется обязательная установка Vk Me

Comment: Удалить сам мессенджер VK Me, либо отключить приложение в настройках.

Comment: удалить то удалишь, но вк сообщения по любому требуют vk me

Comment: в настройках такого пункта нет насчет vk me вообще никаких настроек нет

Comment: Такого в принципе не должно быть, никакие требования со стороны VK Me не выносятся, сам официальный мессенджер располагает поддержкой сообщений. VK Me - это как дополнительная утилита, которая помогает скрыть статус онлайна и получить доступ к сообщениям.

Comment: ну вот, вконтакте заставляет скачать это доп. приложение для общения. я уже погуглил и почитал отзывы, кажется решения не найти.

Comment: тогда можете попробовать установить более старую версию клиента ВК.

Comment: не буду заморачиваться, щас вк никто и не сидит уже. думал, изи решение найду. оказца гемор...